# Activation function is needed in Graph Neural Network?

Tags: graph-neural-network

Activation function is needed in Graph Neural Network?
For example, GCN is the most famous GNN. The performance of SGC, which removes the activation function from the GCN, is the same as that of the GCN.

Comment: What is SGC? Also can you give references to the performance comparison?

Comment: please see this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07153.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As the article shows, not using any nonlinearities doens't seem to hurt performance on some graph tasks. Of course, this is different from saying that a nonlinear activation function *never* helps, in the same way that there are (non-graph) tasks where a linear model is the best choice, and tasks where it isn't.